# mysql query that does not return an id with multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I wasn't sure how to word the title, but here is what I am trying to do. I have a table where the id can have multiple entries

```
id | number
___________
1  | 90
1  | 88
2  | 88
3  | 88
```

I want a query that will return all ids that don't contain the number 90, so only 2 and 3 in this example. I have tried the below, but it still returns the id of 1 since it also has a number of 88.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE number NOT IN (90)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting the result is by using `NOT EXISTS`. Basically what it does it it gets all `ID` which has `90` in the inner query and the `NOT EXISTS` only shows all `ID` not in the inner query.

```
SELECT  A.*
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM TableName B
                    WHERE a.ID = b.ID
                            AND b.number = 90)
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c967/1).

An alternative is by using `LEFT JOIN` which yields the same result as above.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN TableName b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
                AND b.number = 90
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/591d6e/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE number = 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation as illustrated below for better performance:

```
SELECT ID
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING NOT INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(`number`),'90');
```

[**Demo on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68f599).